# ASP .NET state service issue

Tags: asp.net

I have two windows servers running the same ASP .NET project with identical iis settings. If users are using server A, I'd like to shift users to server B. However, the session will not be recognized by server B. Therefore, I have another machine which uses ASP .NET state service that keeps the session.

My sessionState.config:

My machineKey.config:

Unfortunately, this does not work. The ASP .NET state service does not recognize the session for some reason. I tried adding "IsolateApps", using different decrption algorithms, and disabling cookies and host identities. None of the settings works.

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks!

Comment: You didn't share the .config files!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify a machineKey? Taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx#Anchor_1):

> To use StateServer mode in a Web farm, you must have the same encryption keys specified in the machineKey element of your Web configuration for all applications that are part of the Web farm